# PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

In my Spring MVC app, all my `RequestMapping` are getting mapped properly except one. I am unable to figure out why this is getting `PageNotFound` error. For the method `addSatisfaction`, I am getting `PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/CCHPWeb/heart2heart/feedback/102/resolution/satisfaction] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'`.

My `Controller`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/heart2heart/feedback")
public class H2HFeedbackController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(H2HFeedbackController.class);
    private final ActivitiService activitiService;
    private final Heart2HeartService heart2heartService;

    @Autowired
    public H2HFeedbackController(ActivitiService activitiService, Heart2HeartService heart2heartService) {
    super();
    this.activitiService = activitiService;
    this.heart2heartService = heart2heartService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/${feedbackId}/resolution/satisfaction", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getSatisfaction(@PathVariable int feedbackId, Model model) {
    Feedback feedback = new Feedback();
    feedback.setId(feedbackId);
    try {
        feedback = heart2heartService.getFeedbackById(feedback);
        if (feedback.getId() == 0) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "Feedback does not exist");
        model.addAttribute("status", "404 - Not Found");
        return "error";
        }
        model.addAttribute("feedback", feedback);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception :: ", e);
    }
    return "heart2heart/closeFeedback";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{feedbackId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewFeedback(@PathVariable int feedbackId, Model model) {
    Feedback feedback = new Feedback();
    feedback.setId(feedbackId);
    try {
        feedback = heart2heartService.getFeedbackById(feedback);
        if (feedback.getId() == 0) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "Feedback does not exist");
        model.addAttribute("status", "404 - Not Found");
        return "error";
        }
        model.addAttribute("feedback", feedback);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception :: ", e);
    }
    return "heart2heart/feedbackView";
    }
}
```

My `WebApplicationInitializer` is:

```
public class SiteMain implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(MvcConfig.class);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

Comment: The RequestMappings on method level shouldn't have a leading "/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a $ here:

```
/${feedbackId}/resolution/satisfaction
```

change it to

```
/{feedbackId}/resolution/satisfaction
```

`$` stands for 'End of String (or Line)' in regex. I don't think you really need it in your path mapping as it does not make sense for an integer feedbackId.

Comment: This is right. I had copied the link directly from HTML and had got the $ sign with it.

Answer (score 0):

@khateeb, May Problem with web.xml Please find the below web.xml content.`<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>`

Comment: I don't use `web.xml`. I use Java based config. I have updated my question with it. It is similar to your config.

Comment: Try with @Juned Ahsan comments. Generally we mayn't use like this   change  /${feedbackId}/resolution/satisfaction to /{feedbackId}/resolution/satisfaction